# Granular access to objects in S3 bucket via ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to have granular access to certain objects in s3 buckets via ec2 instances. For instance, suppose I have objects OB1 and OB2, and USER1 and USER2 in an ec2 instance, then is it possible to allow USER1 to access only OB1, and allow USER2 to access only OB2.

I know that we can create a policy to connect an s3 bucket to ec2 instance, but was wondering the extent of control I can have on displaying and accessing the objects. With a single user, I tried restricting the object of an S3 bucket by modifying the policy but it didn't work. More precisely, I did the following :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/OB1",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": IP ADDRESS of EC2 instance
                }
            }
        }
        
    ]
}
```

I am curious if we can add an additional condition for users as well. The condition on resource is not good enough, as it still displays the name of all the objects

Comment: Are you saying that you have "two users on the same EC2 instance" or are you saying that "each user has their own EC2 instance"?

Comment: Also, are these 'users' members of your organisation (staff members) or are they users of an application (not staff members)? Do they actually 'login' to the EC2 instance or do they simply interact with a web app running on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. The users are users of an application. They login to the EC2 instance.

Comment: When you say that they "login to the EC2 instance", are you saying that they use SSH/RDP to connect to the instance and run the app, or are they connecting to the application via a web browser? Also, **how are you authenticating these users** to know who they are? Please tell us more about how they are connecting to the EC2 instances, how they are logging in and how you manage them on the instance and operating system.

Comment: Also, how many 'users' do you have, and how many EC2 instances are they accessing? You might do something different if you only have 2 users compared to 2000 users.

Comment: The users are connecting to the instance by SSH. Rather than a password, we will be using key based authentication. It is a toy project, so we will be restricting ourselves to 3-4 users.

Comment: The problem will be associating the SSH Logins to the appropriate AWS Credentials. First, you should create 4 x IAM Users and give each of them appropriate permissions to the S3 bucket. Then, separate 'user' for each of them on the EC2 instance. You should login as each user and use `aws configure` to store the credentials for that user. This way, when they login to the EC2 instance, they already have credentials stored that allow them to access the appropriate part of the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: If your users are staff of your company

Normally, an **IAM Role** is assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance. The permissions from this IAM Role are then available to any software running on the EC2 instance. **All users** who login to the EC2 instance would be able to use these permissions to access Amazon S3 -- **without differentiating between specific users**.

Since you want different users on the instance to have different S3 permissions, **you should not assign an IAM Role to the instance**. Instead, **create an IAM User** for each person and give each person their own personal Access Key + Secret Key. Then, when the users are on the EC2 instance, they can **use their personal credentials** to access S3.

Let's spend a moment to differentiate between 'people', 'users' and the 'instance':

- A **person** (a human) is given their own Access Key + Secret Key by creating an IAM User for each of them.
- A '**user**' on the EC2 instance represents a different login and they have their own directory in the `/home/` directory where they can store their credentials safely without sharing them with other users. The credentials can be stored by running `aws configure` and entering the Access Key + Secret Key. This will be stored in their `~/.aws/credentials` file so that it is available for *their* use but not for anyone who logged in under a different username.
- While the **EC2 instance** traditionally has a login name of `ec2_user`, this is no longer appropriate since you want your 'users' to have different permissions. You will need to [Manage users on your Linux instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) so that **they each have their own login/user name**.

Finally, you can **create an IAM Policy** on each IAM User to grant them specific access to the right part of the S3 bucket, such as this example from [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/):

```json
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndUserListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","Abhi"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["Abhi/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/Abhi/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

This policy would let that user use their own folder within the bucket and list the top-level of the bucket. Please note that when granting permissions to list the contents of a bucket with `ListBucket`, the permissions are granted on the bucket (`"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"`), whereas permissions that grant access to individual objects use a wildcard (`"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/Abhi/*"`).

#### Option 2: If your users are using a web application

If the 'users' you mention are not members of staff and are simply accessing your EC2 instance via  a web application, then you **should not create IAM or Bucket Policies relating to the users**. Instead, **your web application would be responsible for managing all authentication and access to objects in S3**.

It is your web application that makes S3 API calls, so you need to code the web app to ensure users only get access to objects in S3 to which they are entitled.